# Go определение типа уязвимости и предложения по его предотвращению

Tags: golang, service

Имеется следующий код:

```
func race(){
    wait := make(chan struct())
    n := 0
    go func () {
        n++
    }()

    n++
    fmt.Println(n)
}
```

И следующее ТЗ:

К какой уязвимости приведет реализация этого функционала? Опишите уязвимость и предложите свои варианты предотвращения.

Всё что я могу сказать по этому поводу, так это то что "n" по итогу будет 1, а не 2, а так же может возникнуть ошибка из-за того, что "wait" не используется...

Я вижу данный код следующим образом для корректной отработки:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    wait := make(chan int)
    n := 0
    go func() {
        wait <- 1
    }()
    n += <-wait
    n++
    fmt.Println(n)
}
```

Но я не думаю, что такое банальное решение является решением. У кого какие идеи и предположения?

Comment: читайте про ключевое слово `go` и горутины

Answer (score 0):

#### Достаточно обратить внимание на название функции :)

Этот код создает ситуацию гонки ([race condition](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8)).

В данном случае, одновременно выполняются две операции: горутина (`go func()`) увеличивает n на 1, и основной поток **также** увеличивает `n` на 1.

Так как порядок выполнения этих операций **не** определен, n может быть либо 1, либо 2 в момент вывода, в зависимости от того, какой поток выполнился первым. Это делает поведение программы **непредсказуемым** и потенциально ошибочным.

Чтобы предотвратить эту уязвимость, можно использовать [механизмы синхронизации, такие как мьютексы (`mutexes`) или каналы (`channels`), чтобы гарантировать, что только один поток может изменять переменную в данный момент времени.

#### Пример с использованием мьютекса:

```go
func race() {
    var mu sync.Mutex
    n := 0
    go func() {
        mu.Lock()
        n++
        mu.Unlock()
    }()

    mu.Lock()
    n++
    mu.Unlock()
    fmt.Println(n)
}
```

> В этом примере `mu.Lock()` **блокирует** доступ к переменной `n` для
> других потоков, пока текущий поток не вызовет `mu.Unlock()`, после
> чего доступ к `n` становится возможным для других потоков.

#### Пример с использованием канала:

```go
func race() {
    n := 0
    done := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        n++
        done <- true
    }()

    n++
    <-done
    fmt.Println(n)
}
```

> Здесь канал `done` используется для синхронизации потоков. Горутина
> отправляет значение в канал `done` после увеличения `n`, и основной
> поток ждет это значение перед выводом `n`, что обеспечивает
> **последовательное** увеличение `n`.

Comment: Единственное, мне интересно, автор говорит именно об уязвимости или о некорректности. Потому как уязвимость - это возможность вмешаться в процесс и выведать какие-то конфиденциальные данные или хакнуть защиту. А если программа работает неправильно - то она впринципе, как уже сказано, совершенно не предсказуема.

Comment: Да, хорошее замечание, описанное мною, не является уязвимостью по определению, здесь речь больше про некорректное и/или непредсказуемое поведение.

Comment: Ну в ТЗ речь идëт именно об уязвимости, эти задания в принципе трудно понимаемые, было похожее, где как ответ в итоге оказалось, что если вызывать код содержащий в себе ошибку, можно устраивать dos атаки

Comment: @ЧетвёртыйКэп получится разместить это на Github, чтобы посмотреть?

Comment: Можно ctrl+c ctrl+v сделать, это всë что дано, ни строчки больше